# Spock - repeating tests with different system defaults

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, timezone, spock

I have a Spock spec for testing a method that takes a `java.util.Date`.

```
def "special dates are identified correctly"() {
    expect:
        isSpecialDay(Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', date)) == special
    where:
        date         | special
        '2010/01/01' | false
        '2011/01/01' | true
        '2012/01/01' | true
        '2013/01/01' | false
        '2014/01/01' | true
        // and lots more...
}
```

I want to ensure that TimeZone doesn't make a difference in my method implementation (i.e. Jan 1st, 2011 is special regardless if I'm in EST or GMT or whatever). **Is there a way I can repeatedly execute the test method in a single run with a different, default timezone per execution?**

I could add a third column to the "where" block for the TimeZone, but that extra dimension would make the table too big for my liking.

Currently, I'm setting a random default per test run, but I don't like the fact that my test is not repeatable and, if there's a failure, the problematic TimeZone isn't captured in the assertion message.

```
@Shared TimeZone defaultTz = TimeZone.getDefault()

def setupSpec() {
    def tzIds = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()
    def randomTzId = tzIds[new Random().nextInt(tzIds.length)]
    def randomTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(randomTzId)
    println "Using TimeZone $randomTz for test spec"
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(randomTzId));
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(defaultTz)
}
```

Comment: parse - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html - is overriden and accepts `TimeZone` argument. I'd add a `tz` column in data table and put there random time zones. Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: @Opal - it's possible, but if I wanted to be thorough, my table would increase by 100 lines for each timezone I wanted to check (my actual where block is 100 lines at the moment)

Comment: You can randomize this process. Do not add TŻ to table but choose it randomly from e.g. predefined collection.

Comment: It really sounds like you should not be using `java.util.Date`, but rather [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (Java8) or [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (Joda-Time, Java <= 7).  The Java `Date` is not really a date, it's an instantaneous absolute point in time.  It will vary by time zone.  A `LocalDate` is just a Year, Month, and Day without any particular time or time zone involved.

Comment: @MattJohnson - it's too late for this project, but rest assured, I'll definitely be going with Java 8 or Joda for future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `JodaTime` you can test the same for all available time zones using`DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`. Here is a quick and nasty implementation to show case how it cane be done.

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.9')
@Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='1.0-groovy-2.4')

import spock.lang.*
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone

class TestSpecialDate extends Specification {

    def "special dates are identified correctly"() {
        expect:
        DateTimeZone.availableIDs.each { tz ->
            // get current moment in default time zone
            DateTime dt = new DateTime( Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', date ) )

            // translate to local date time
            DateTime dtLocal = dt.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( tz ) )

            // Get Java Date and assert  
            assert isSpecialDay( dtLocal.toDate() ) == special
        }

        where:
        date         || special
        '2010/01/07' || false
        '2011/01/01' || true
        '2012/01/01' || true
        '2013/11/06' || false
        '2014/01/01' || true
    }

    // Mimic special day implementation
    static private boolean isSpecialDay(Date date) {
        // Check if it is the first day of month
        return date[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] == 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great! You can replace `each` with `every` and eliminate the assert statement, however debugging may be harder.

Comment: Tried that, been there. ;)

Comment: *cough* list of timezones, list of dates, `combinations` and the `<<` form of where blocks with @Unroll? (hint)

Comment: @Opal Debugging was harder as you mentioned.

Comment: @tim_yates That is cool. Will it be intuitive to have boolean list of `special` to assert? I will give that a try as soon as I can.

Comment: I'd have a list of date/boolean, and a list of timezones. Get the combinations, and extract from that?

Comment: Yes, that would be good. Please feel free to add/modify answer with that approach. I would love to try that right now instead of thumb typing. :) @tim_yates

Comment: I'm on my thumbs too ATM... Hence hints ;-)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I haven't got a chance to try it yet, but it appears the key is the except block's assert within the each closure. I was unaware that was possible.

Comment: @bdkosher added my Unrolled version below :-)

Comment: I like @tim_yates approach, too, but I'm going to go with this one on account of it preserving the table-like formatting in the where block. Even though the TZ isn't explicitly asserted, I still get to see which TZ is in play when Spock outputs the date value (e.g. "Mon May 28 00:00:00 SST 2012")

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using the combinations trick I hinted at above:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.9')
@Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='1.0-groovy-2.4')

import spock.lang.*
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone

class TestSpecialDate extends Specification {
    @Shared def zoneCombinations = [
        DateTimeZone.availableIDs,
        [[date:'2010/01/07', special:false], [date:'2011/01/01', special:true], [date:'2012/01/01', special:true],
         [date:'2013/11/06', special:false], [date:'2014/01/01', special:true]]]
             .combinations { a, b -> [zone:a, date:b.date, special:b.special] }


    @Unroll
    def "#date for #zone should be special #special"() {
        expect:
        // get current moment in default time zone
        DateTime dt = new DateTime( Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', date ) )

        // translate to local date time
        DateTime dtLocal = dt.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( zone ) )

        // Get Java Date and assert  
        isSpecialDay( dtLocal.toDate() ) == special


        where:
        date << zoneCombinations.date
        special << zoneCombinations.special
        zone << zoneCombinations.zone
    }

    // Mimic special day implementation
    static private boolean isSpecialDay(Date date) {
        // Check if it is the first day of month
        return date[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] == 1
    }
}
```

When executed in the groovy console, that runs:

```
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 2915, Failures: 0, Time: 351
```

2915 tests :-)

Comment: Splendid variation :)